Keras Transformer regression model not predicting values beyond a threshold
I am working on a keras transformer model for regression and I am getting prediction values which are cut off to some specific threshold.
Code:
def transformer_block(self,inputs, embed_dim, num_heads, ff_dim, dropout_rate):
        
    x = inputs
    x = MultiHeadAttention(key_dim=embed_dim,num_heads=num_heads,dropout=dropout_rate)(x, x)
    #x = Dropout(dropout_rate)(x)
    res = x + inputs

    # Feed Forward Part
    x = LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(res)
    x = Dense(ff_dim, activation="relu")(x)
    x = Dropout(dropout_rate)(x)
    x = Dense(inputs.shape[-1])(x)
    return x + res
# Build the model
def create_model(self, embed_dim = 64, num_heads = 6,
        ff_dim = 128, num_transformer_blocks = 3,
        dropout_rate = 0.1):
        
    vocab_size,input_length = self.vocab_size,self.input_length,
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(input_length,), dtype=tf.int32)
    embedding_layer = keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size,
    output_dim=embed_dim)(inputs)

    x = embedding_layer
    
    for _ in range(num_transformer_blocks):
        x = self.transformer_block(x, embed_dim, num_heads, ff_dim, dropout_rate)
        x = LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(x) 
        x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(x)
        x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(x)
        
    f = ff_dim
        
    while(f//2 > 1):                
        x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(f//2, activation='relu')(x)
        x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(x)
        f = f//2
            
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'linear')(x)  # Regression output
    
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    return model

True vs Predicted Graph:

A previous question mentioned not to use tanh or sigmoid activation functions but I am only using relu (I also tried gelu and leaky relu). I tried adding more transformer layers but still get this problem. Can some one explain why I'm getting this and how to mitigate it?
